# Controller Inheritance in TypeScript giving Unknown Provider tProvider <- t Error

Tags: angularjs, typescript

My code has 2 child controllers extending a parent.

```
export class ParentController{
   constructor(public A: service A, public B: service B, public C: service C)
}

export class ChildController1 extends ParentController{
   constructor(A: service A, B: service B, C: service C);
   super(A,B,C);
}

export class ChildController2 extends ParentController{
   constructor(A: service A, B: service B, C: service C);
   super(A,B,C);
}
```

While the code runs perfectly without minification, it gives a **Unknown provider: tProvider <- t error**  when I run the minifeld version.

I did read about $injector but I don't understand how to use it in Typescript.

Is there a better way to represent my code or is it something very obvious that I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t` service name indicates that the application was minified. In order for it to work properly, all DI units should be [annotated](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation).

The preferable way to annotate classes is [static `$inject` property](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation). In TypeScript and ES.next it can be specified as [static class field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties):

```
export class ParentController{
   static $inject = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

   constructor(public A: service A, public B: service B, public C: service C) {}
}
```

If child controllers share same set of dependencies and don't need own constructors, `constructor` and `$inject` can be omitted in child classes.

Comment: I won't be able to check on my sandbox env until tomorrow, but this should work. Thanks a lot! Also, could you please point me to the associated documentation. I searched for over a couple of hours for this before asking you! Thanks again :D