# Controller inheritance in Typescript with minification causing Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider

Tags: angularjs, typescript, minify, angularjs-controller, grunt-contrib-uglify

**UPDATE 2019/07/16**

My issue is actually caused by the inappropriate use of `$inject`. I used it as `private $inject` in `api-service.ts` but it should be `public static $inject = [...]`. When uglifying, it relies on the explicit injection but `private $inject` made it implicit

---

I have a very much the same issue with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372160/controller-inheritance-in-typescript-giving-unknown-provider-tprovider-t-erro). Instead of the `tProvider` unknown, my error message has the specific provider name but look like

> Unknown provider: eProvider <- e <- api-service <- baseDI-service

where `api-service` and `baseDI-service` are named and registered services for the same module.

My module looks like as below:

```
module
--api-service
--other-services
--baseDI-service
--componentA
----controllerA extends BaseController
--componentB
----controllerB extends BaseController
```

I import `api-service` and other services in `baseDI-service` which I used as a service container because I don't want to pass a lot parameters in `super()` of componentA, for example.

So in componentA it looks like:

```
...
class ComponentAController extends BaseController {
    public static $inject = ['baseDI-service', ...];

    constructor(baseDIService: BaseDIService) {
        ...
        super(baseDIService); 
        ...
    }
}
```

`BaseDIService.ts`:

```
export default class BaseControllerDIService {
    public static $inject = ['api-service', '$http', ...];
    constructor(
        private apiSvc: ApiService,
        private $http: ng.IHttpService,
        ...
    ) {}

    public getBaseClassDependencies() {
        return{
            apiService: this.apiSvc,
            $http : this.$http
            ... : ...
        };
    }
}
```

`BaseController.ts`

```
export default class BaseController implements ng.IComponentController {    
    apiService: ApiService;
    $http: ng.IHttpService;

    constructor(
        baseDIService: BaseDIService
    ) {
        const services = baseDIService.getBaseClassDependencies();
        this.$http = services.$http;        
        this.apiSvc = services.apiService;
        ...
        this.otherService = services.otherServices;
        ...
    }
```

After **Grunt Uglify** minification, the error was like Unknown provider: serviceAProvider <- serviceA. Without minification, everything alright.

Prior to this way, I also tried using `$injector` the same way as `baseDI-service` in controllerA to pass it to `super()`, and in BaseController I use `$injector.get('api-service')`, I got the same issue with minification only.

Could anyone tell why both way I tried failed in **Uglify** minified mode, and how can sort it out? I do need minification by the way.

Also, is it a good practice using controller inheritance for AngularJS?

Comment: Hi @georgeawg, if I pass the constructor parameters to BaseController through derived controllers, I still need $inject to state the required parameters again?

Comment: The problem is with the dependency injection for the `api-service`. Make sure that it has a proper `$inject` property. Show us the code for that service.

Comment: You just made a correct point and it did help me figure out the issue! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help you find this kind of problem before you uglify, use Strict Dependency Injection.

From the Docs:

> ## Using Strict Dependency Injection
>
> You can add an `ng-strict-di` directive on the same element as `ng-app` to opt into strict DI mode:
>
> ```
> <!doctype html>
> <html ng-app="myApp" ng-strict-di>
> <body>
>   I can add: {{ 1 + 2 }}.
>   <script src="angular.js"></script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Strict mode throws an error whenever a service tries to use implicit annotations.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Strict Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#using-strict-dependency-injection)

Comment: Thanks very much georgeawg. I tried ng-strict-di it didn't throw any error though. The point is your suggestion actually indicated me to check if there's any implicit injection and I found I wrote `private $inject = [...]` in `api-service` and I think this is where disaster started. I changed it to `public static $inject = ...` and uglified it, now it works!!